# Type mismatch: Cannot convert from java.sql.statement to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is the code I am working with to connect to a mysql database.

I am getting this error: Type mismatch: Cannot convert from java.sql.statement to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement

The line:  Statement getData=con.createStatement(); //ERROR HERE

Do I have a class loading issue?

```
//connect to database

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Date;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement; 



public class dbconn {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Databasename";

        try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement getData=con.createStatement(); //ERROR HERE
        ResultSet rs = getData.executeQuery("select * from MY_TABLE_NAME");
        while(rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getDate(1));
        con.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}


    }


}
```

Comment: you should import `import java.sql.Statement` not `com.mysql.jdbc.Statement`

Answer (score 4):

This statement:

```
 Statement getData = con.createStatement();
```

won't compile because the signature of `createStatement()` says that it returns a `java.sql.Statement`.  But you have imported `com.mysql.jdbc.Statement`, and that means that `Statement` *means* `com.mysql.jdbc.Statement`.

Solutions:

1. Fix the `import` statement (preferred!!).
2. Cast the returned value to `Statement`.  This kind of works, but you are doing an unnecessary runtime type-check (that could fail!) AND the code *will* break if you change your JDBC driver to some other vendor's.

Lessons:

1. Don't blindly accept your IDE's suggestions / completions for imports.  They may be incorrect.
2. If you are designing an API yourself, avoid the temptation of picking a class or interface name that is the same one used in the Java SE class libraries.